# Boolean Function question

Tags: logic

I need to know how I can prove this question. 
Prove that not every boolean function is equal to a boolean function constructed by only using And ($\wedge$) and Or ($\vee$)

Answer (score 1):

Consider a function $f$ where $f(\text{true}, \text{true}) = \text{false}$.  Can you see how any function with this property can't be created with $\land$ and $\lor$?